# Twitter Api Request Token Url Issues

Tags: url, twitter, request, token, twitter-oauth

I need help with twitter API. `request_token` results in an error:

```
Could Not Authendicate You... Authorization Required.
```

My code is:

```
var url="https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?";
url+="&oauth_callback=" +callbackUrl;
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:'POST',
    data: {},
    async :true,
    beforeSend:function(xhr){
       xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','OAuth oauth_consumer_key="3lqppVjoq7snHzGkvlab7uSix ", oauth_nonce="f7998b22bed5df683dc2f54c0a0679b3 ", oauth_signature="0CSKKi1hy901Mh6uHdLnL%2FDUXwE%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp= "1458408374 ", oauth_token, "403211404-jJsPD74gOelV7wFcSfoaRwfWAnZqsB9ysXDTO5ox", oauth_version="1.0"');
    },    
    success: function(data){
         alert(data);
    },
    error:function(error){
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I can immediately see:

1. The [Twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/request_token) state that you should include all oauth_* parameters in the header if you are using HTTP-header based OAuth (this includes the oauth_callback parameter).
2. The oauth_token parameter is not part of the initial request token flow (because you haven't obtained a token yet) and so should be removed from the Authorization header.

Obviously check that your signature is correct which you can do with an online signature generator such as [this one](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/signature.html).